# How to display all dataframe column in a Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, series

i need to show all the nulls values in the dataframe in a Series using sum(), but I can only see the firsts 5 values and the last ones.

[image: Series]

Comment: Yes, it does! Thank you!  I used pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
df.isna().sum()

Answer (score -1):

If you want to see everything on screen you will need to change your pandas display settings:

pandas.options.display.max_rows =